# np.pad() converting my array into a new array with only values equal to 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, padding

I am working on a NLP machine learning project and I want to add some additional data to the original dataset used in training to compare results. To this end, the shape of my new dataset which is a numpy array (i.e. numpy array with previous data + additional data) needs to match the shape of the test set used in the first round of training.

When I used the code below to pad my numpy array, I noticed that all the float numbers disappeared and I got a new array containing only zeros specially if I reassign with a new variable.

```
Xfeatures_new_pad =np.pad(Xfeatures_new, (2039, 0), 'constant')
```

The same happens if I use pad_sequences():

```
Xfeatures_new_pad=pad_sequences(Xfeatures_new, maxlen=Xfeatures_train.shape[1], 
padding='pre')
```

I have also tried the below code:

```
result = np.zeros(Xfeatures_train.shape)
result[:Xfeatures_new.shape[0],:Xfeatures_new.shape[1]] = 
Xfeatures_new
new_Xfeatures=result[:Xfeatures_new.shape[0]]
new_Xfeatures_train = np.concatenate((Xfeatures_train, 
new_Xfeatures), axis=0)


result_y = np.zeros(y_train.shape)
result_y[:y_train_new.shape[0],:y_train_new.shape[1]] = 
y_train_new
new_y=result_y[:y_train_new.shape[0]]
new_y_train = np.concatenate((y_train, new_y), axis=0)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-33-a696a6ccc21c> in <module>()
  1 
  2 result = np.zeros(Xfeatures_train.shape)
----> 3 result[:Xfeatures_new.shape[0],:Xfeatures_new.shape[1]] = 
Xfeatures_new
  4 new_Xfeatures=result[:Xfeatures_new.shape[0]]
  5 new_Xfeatures_train = np.concatenate((Xfeatures_train, 
new_Xfeatures), axis=0)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape 
(600,13072) into shape (400,13072)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you add a minimum data set into your post that is able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `Xfeatures_new`?

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of the result?

Comment: @hpaulj, shape of Xfeatures_new is (600, 13072) and I need it to become (600, 15111). Type is numpy.ndarray

Comment: @hpaulj, I updated my question with another approach I am trying, but got an error

Comment: I asked for `dtype`.  That the `type` is `ndarray` is obvious.  Do you understand what I mean by `dtype`?  And when asking about an error like that `broadcasting` one, show the traceback.  I shouldn't have to guess or deduce which line caused the problem.

Comment: I suspect your `result` isn't big enough.  If `x=np.zeros((10,12))`, `x[:20,:]` will still be (10,12), not (20,12).

Comment: I already have a solution to the problem. I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my code was that the empty array with zeros created had less rows than the number of rows of the array that was supposed to be inserted in it. The solution was to specify the same number of rows I needed in order to accommodate the shape of the array I wanted to insert in the empty array.

```
result = np.zeros(600, 15111)

result[:Xfeatures_new.shape[0],:Xfeatures_new.shape[1]] = 
Xfeatures_new
```